# python script runs from command line but using subprocess gives error

Tags: python, subprocess

the following command line works and gives correct results

```
$ python maps2.py -i=/media/babak/LaCie/necessary/visualisation/CMIP3_Babak/Temperature/bccr_bcm2_0 -o=temp/CMIP3 -p=temp_001
```

but when the exact command is called, using the following subprocess module:

```
run=subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'maps2.py -i=/media/babak/LaCie/necessary/visualisation/CMIP3_Babak/Temperature/bccr_bcm2_0 -o=temp/CMIP3 -p=temp_001' ])
```

it gives the following error:

```
/usr/bin/python: can't open file 'maps2.py -i=/media/babak/LaCie/necessary/visualisation/CMIP3_Babak/Temperature/bccr_bcm2_0 -o=temp/CMIP3 -p=temp_001': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

what's the reason? the commands are exactly the same.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `subprocess.Popen()` the first argument should be a list with a separate entry for each argument to the process you want to run:

```
run=subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'maps2.py', '-i=/media/babak/LaCie/necessary/visualisation/CMIP3_Babak/Temperature/bccr_bcm2_0', '-o=temp/CMIP3', '-p=temp_001' ])
```

What you currently have would be the equivalent to running the following on the command line:

```
python 'maps2.py -i=/media/babak/LaCie/necessary/visualisation/CMIP3_Babak/Temperature/bccr_bcm2_0 -o=temp/CMIP3 -p=temp_001'
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to F.J.'s answer, you can easily split the name of the executable from the arguments with `shlex.split`

```
mapsCommand = 'maps2.py -i=/media/babak/LaCie/necessary/visualisation/CMIP3_Babak/Temperature/bccr_bcm2_0 -o=temp/CMIP3 -p=temp_001'
fullCommand = [sys.executable]
fullCommand.extend(shlex.split(mapsCommand))
run=subprocess.Popen(fullCommand)
```